# table + foreach - new column?

Tags: php, html, foreach, html-table

```
<?php
$values = array();
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
 $values[$i] = "aaa" . $i;
} ?>
<table>
<?php
foreach ($values as $i => $val) {

echo "<tr><td>" . $val . "</td> </tr>";
} ?>
</table>
```

this generated me:

```
aaa1
aaa2
...
aaa50
...
aaa90
...
aaa100
```

how can I make two column?

```
aaa1   aaa50
aaa2   ....
...    aaa90
aaa50  aaa100
```

but no:

```
aaa1 aaa2
aaa3 aaa4
...  ....
aaa99 aaa100
```

Comment: good comment, it also depends a lot on what he is planning to do afterwards with the table data

Comment: Do you have to stick with <table> tag? There is a nice solution with a different tags structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that I would do this is to create two separate tables (each one column wide) and then include both of them in a single, two-columned table:

```
<?php
$list=array('a','b','c','d','e','f');
$midpoint=floor(count($list)/2);
$tableHeader='<table width="100%">';
$tableFooter='</table>';
$leftTable=$tableHeader;
$rightTable=$tableHeader;
for ($c=0; $c<$midpoint; $c++)
{
    $leftTable.='<tr><td width="100%">'.$list[$c].'</td></tr>';
}
$leftTable.=$tableFooter;
for ($c=$midpoint; $c<count($list); $c++)
{
    $rightTable.='<tr><td width="100%">'.$list[$c].'</td></tr>';
}
$rightTable.=$tableFooter;
$mainTable='<table><tr><td width="50%">'.$leftTable.'</td><td width="50%">'.$rightTable.'</td></tr></table>';
echo $mainTable;
?>
```

Add some CSS to remove padding around the sub-tables and borders etc and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Try if this works for you. Regardless of the format of the items contained in $values, it should print the array the way you want.

```
<?php

$size = count($values);
$halfSize = intval(ceil($size / 2));

for ($i = 0; $i < $halfSize; $i++) 
{
    $j = $i + $halfSize;

    echo "<tr><td>" . $values[$i]  . "</td>";

    // If $size is odd, $halfSize is rounded up. This means that if we have 
    // 3 elements, it will try to access to $values[3], since $halfSize would
    // be 2. The last second column element should be blank in this case.
    // So, if $halfSize is odd, and $i is the last element, don't print an
    // additional table cell.

    if (!($i == $halfSize - 1 && $size % 2 == 1))
        echo "<td>" . $values[$j]  . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
} 

?>
```

Comment: thanks, but this generated for me first column : 1-100 (should 1-50) and in second column 50-100 (this ok)

Answer (score 1):

a function

```
function sqlArr($sql){
  $ret = array();
  $res = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$sql);
  if ($res) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
      $ret[] = $row;
    }
  }
  return $ret;
}
```

a code

```
$temp = sqlArr("SELECT value FROM table");
$data = array();
for($i=0;$i<50;$i++){
  $data[] = array($temp[$i],$temp[$i+50]);
}
unset($temp);
```

a template

```
<table border='1'>
<? foreach ($data as $i => $row): ?>
  <tr>
  <? foreach ($row as $cell): ?>
    <td><?=$cell?></td>
  <? endforeach ?>
  </tr>
<? endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already numbered it, just abstract it down:

```
a1  a51
a2  a52
...
a49 a99
a50 a100
```

is exactly the same as

```
a1  a1+50
a2  a2+50
...
a50 a50+50
```

This makes you having the following code:

```
echo "<table>";

for($i=1; $i<=50; $i++) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $i . "</td><td>" . ($i+50) . "</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

**Note:** This requires you to let the table be generated this way. If it's actually not numbered like that, you would have to figure out another way to generate the abstract table in my listing 2 (just think about the index the entries have in relation to their left neighbor).

Comment: i will this values get for database, this isnt number